# How to use mongoose virtuals in a find result

Tags: mongoose

I had this pretty weired problem with using virtuals. As can be seen in the below code example, when I am using find, in order for virtuals to appear in the result, I have to also include the base columns from which the virtuals have been created. Is there any alternative to this? Otherwise I have to select both base and virtuals everytime I use find?

```
PersonSchema = new Schema({
    fname: {type: String, required: true},
    lname: String,
    bday: {type: Date, required: true},
    share: mongoose.Decimal128,
},{toObject:{virtuals:true}, toJSON:{virtuals:true}});

PersonSchema.virtual('desc').get(function(){
    const birth = this.bday.getMonth() + this.bday.getFullYear();
    return this.fname + ' ' + this.lname + ' ' + this.share + '% ' ;
});
PersonSchema.virtual('Share').get(function(){ return this.share.toString});
const selectList = 'fname lname share bday desc Share';

PersonSchema.methods.getData = function() {
    Persons.find({}, selectList, function(err, persons){
        const data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(persons, {virtuals: true}));
        console.log('persons', persons);
     }).limit(5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are trying to set the display of virtuals in the options, have you tried using the set method instead?

```
PersonSchema.set('toJSON', { virtuals: true });
```